# Trying to cast a panel to JOptionPane

Tags: jpanel, joptionpane, dice

I am trying to cast a Panel into a JOptionPane information message, the panel will eventually contain multiple images depending on the rolls of two dice. I am trying to get the image of the dice to populate after three rolls, after which i will include stats about the dice rolls. However when running the program the JOptionpane pops up empty (Even when the users dice1 or dice2 is 1) 
Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Dice extends JFrame {

   public static void main(String[] args){
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.minimumSize", new Dimension(500,500));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#"); //how to display percentage of results
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many times would you like to roll the dice?");
        int rolls = sc.nextInt();
        int[] counts = new int[rolls]; //creates an array of user-specified length (rolls)
        sc.close();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3 && i < counts.length; i++){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int dice1 = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        int dice2 = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        System.out.println((dice1) + " " + (dice2));
        counts[i] = dice1+dice2;
        if(dice1 == 1 || dice2 == 1){
        ImageIcon dice01img = new ImageIcon("/diceface01.gif");
        JLabel diceface01 = new JLabel(dice01img);
        panel.add(diceface01); 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,panel,"Information",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
        }
        else {
         System.out.println("Nothing yet"); }
        }
        for(int i = 3; i < counts.length; i++){ //populates said array with each roll of the dice
            counts[i] = diceRoll();
            if(i < 3){
            System.out.println(counts[i]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a `JPanel` to add an image to a `JOptionPane`.

you can do something like this:

```
if(dice1 == 1 || dice2 == 1){
    //Just an example path here
    ImageIcon dice01img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\ball.jpg");

    //Here you just have to pass your `ImageIcon` in the last parameter of your `JOptionPane` and it'll work as you wished.     
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HELLO", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, dice01img);
}
```